# Is there any way to go back to the old "classic Gmail"?

Tags: gmail

Google won't allow it anymore, now that the settings ⚙ button no longer has the **`Go back to classic Gmail`** option. But I miss the old interface because of

- higher information density
- better fonts
- less unnecessary whitespace
- ability to hover over date and see timestamp in list view

Has anyone created a chrome extension or some other way to use gmail with the old look and feel?

Comment: @Rubén the possible duplicate Q's answer no longer works... so it's not really answered anymore.

Comment: @Xen2050 The answer mentions  that one day the new UI will be permanent. Thatt happened several weeks ago.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering what happens to old questions if their answers change, (there's probably a meta question about it somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

to reactivate the old hover behaviour : Go to `Settings`, under `General settings` look for `Hover actions` and select `Disable hover actions` then `Save Changes`.